# Set Map Boundaries For Kivy Garden MapView

Tags: python, maps, kivy

I am using Garden-MapView in my Kivy app.

My issue is that the user can move outside the bounds of the map (pulled from OpenStreetMap) and continue to pan into the surrounding blue 'sea' area. Image below:

[image]

I'm not sure if the issue is specific to Garden-MapView, or if a generic kivy/widget answer could solve it.

My best attempt to solve this (out of many) is some crude code posted below. When the map extents move past the edge of the screen, the code calculates the center screen coordinate and pulls the center of the map to it. It works better for longitude. But this can slow down the app significantly due to the frequency of on_map_relocated event calls. I have also set MapView.min_zoom = 2:

```
class CustMapView(MapView):
    def on_map_relocated(self, *kwargs):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.get_bbox()
        centerX, centerY = Window.center
        latRemainder = self.get_latlon_at(centerX, centerY, zoom=self.zoom)[0]-(x1+x2)/2
        if x1 < -85.8: self.center_on((x1+x2)/2+latRemainder+.01, self.lon)
        if x2 > 83.6: self.center_on((x1+x2)/2+latRemainder-.01, self.lon)
        if y1 == -180: self.center_on(self.lat, (y1+y2)/2+0.01)
        if y2 == 180: self.center_on(self.lat, (y1+y2)/2-0.01)
```

Full code to reproduce yourselves: https://pastebin.com/xX0GtPUb